# Get SOAP Header xml from SOAP UI tool

Tags: xml, web-services, soapui

I am using SOAP UI to send a request. The xml I pass is something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pws="http://PWS">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <psw:Method1...>

           <pws:model query="">
               <pws:keys query="">
                    <pws:MyID type="String" ...></pws:MyID>
               </pws:keys>
           </psw:model>
        </psw:Method1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The `<soapenv:Header/>` section is set by SOAP UI and I do not know how can I view it from the tool. How can I see the full SOAP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request editor, you would see a tab `Raw` on the left side. Just click that one once the request is sent from soapui.

You can find the exact data that was sent to the endpoint including the soap `Header` information.

Here is the sample screen depicting the same.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
If you intended to see some data under `soap header`, then you need to add the credentials in the request properties which will be appearing on left side of the request editor.

For more details, please see the documentation [here](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html)

Comment: there I only see `<soapenv:Header/>`... And I also do not see authentication info in the Body either

Comment: Please see the updated answer. By the way, the orginal question posted has been clarified already, I believe.

Comment: that is where I did add credentials but somehow it is not reflected in the header

Comment: Have you followed the link completely? ANyway, you wanted to see how you can find the details which was answered.